# Change RewriteRule to cover subfolders and original folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I use a rule like below to apply a watermark to my jpg images.

```
RewriteRule (.*)images/photos/(.*) $1watermark.php?p=br&q=90&src=images/photos/$2
```

Images used to be in `images/photos`, but now I need to move some images to subfolders. For the subfolders I now get **x and y error**. These are some examples of subfolders:

- images/photos/2015-05-10
- images/photos/2015-05-10/people
- images/photos/2015-05-10/cityes
- images/photos/2015-05-09
- images/photos/2015-05-10/others
- images/photos/2015-05-10/cook

Would I be able to make a rule that works for all subfolders and the regular folder? Something like: `images/photos/[all folders and subfolders]/(.*)`.

Comment: It is unclear what's not working and what's being asked here.

Comment: Made some changes, but it's still unclear what the problem is with the current rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)images/photos(/.+)?$ $1show.php?p=br&q=90&src=images/photos$2 [L]
```